# Javascript - Are multiple setInterval's good way?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, intervals

I want to do some stuff in every 20 seconds, the other one in every 30 seconds, and the other one in every 40 seconds. This is what I would do for this situtation:

```
const seconds = 1000;
setInterval(doStuff1, 20 * seconds);
setInterval(doStuff2, 30 * seconds);
setInterval(doStuff3, 40 * seconds);
```

However, this does not look like a good way for me. Also, it might slow down the bot(doesn't matter what bot it is) a little bit, but a little bit is not that important since it is a background bot.

Is this the most correct way?

Comment: What's your concern? Why do you think this may not be the right solution? If you're not creating too many (thousands of) timers, and if the order of execution and precise timing doesn't matter, then this is a good, straightforward solution.

Comment: @ArashMotamedi Yes, I was worried about it; thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be too much of a deal to have three `setIntervals` but if you don't have any restriction on needing to have a control over stopping a certain interval at the click of a button, then you can may be consider something like this.

```
const seconds = 1000;
const time = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  time += 10

  (time % 20 === 0) && doStuff1();

  (time % 30 === 0) && doStuff2();

  (time % 40 === 0) && doStuff3();

}, 10 * seconds);
```

There is no great optimisation that comes out of this but it's just a easy way to remember the intervals you initiated which is only one rather than having multiple and forgetting to `clearInterval` on one at a later point in time.

There is no overhead as well. Your 3 intervals at 20, 30 and 40 will trigger 10 times in a 100 second span which is the same with the one 10 interval.

**100 seconds**

3 intervals - 10 invocations

1 interval - 10 invocations

**200 seconds**

3 intervals - 21 invocations

1 interval - 20 invocations

**300 seconds**

3 intervals - 32 invocations

1 interval - 30 invocations

Comment: So, I think I'm gonna use the way I used because you said 3 timers are okay, thanks for this solution too though.